# Node.js 16.xからNode.js 18.xにコード変更したら動作しない

Tags: aws, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

留守番電話を実装するため、下記参考サイトのWAV形式に変換してS3に保存するLambdaを利用して、問題なく動作しておりましたが、Node.js 16.xからNode.js 18.xにコード変更したところ、WAVファイルは作成されますが、中身が0バイトとなり、再生することができません。

参考サイト：
[留守番電話3（kinesis Video StreamsデータをWAV形式に変換してS3に保存） - Qiita](https://qiita.com/echolimitless/items/af068e147e233c51d6a4)

Node.js 18.xコード

```
const region = 'ap-northeast-1';
const putKey = 'wav/';
const bucketName = 'my-baseXXXXXXXXX';

// S3インポート
// import { ebml } from './node/nodejs';
const ebml = import('ebml');
console.log(`===ebml===：${ebml}`);
console.log('process.env.NODE_PATH==');
console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH);

// 「test-voice-message-infomation」でS3に保存されたデータ（発信者番号、ストリーム名、フラグメント番号など）をもとに、
// Amazon Kinesis Video Streamsから、RAWファイルをWAVファイルに変換し、S3に保存する。

const region = 'ap-northeast-1';
const putKey = 'voice-message/wav/';
const bucketName = 'testname-pjcode';

// S3インポート
import { GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
// Amazon Kinesis Videoインポート
import { KinesisVideoClient, GetDataEndpointCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-kinesis-video";
// Amazon Kinesis Video mediaインポート
import { KinesisVideoMediaClient, GetMediaCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-kinesis-video-media";
const kvmClient = new KinesisVideoMediaClient({ region : region });
// ebmlのインポート ★importの書き方がよくわからない★
// const ebml = import('ebml');

    
export const handler = async (event) => {

    console.log('==process.env.NODE_PATH==')
    console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

    const region = 'ap-northeast-1';
    const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: region }); 
    
    for (let record of event.Records) {
        // information/yyyymmdd_×××をgetKeyに格納
        const getKey = record.s3.object.key;
        
        // '/'までの文字数10がindexに格納
        let index = getKey.lastIndexOf('/');
        let fileName = 'noname';
        
        if (index >= 0) {
            // getKeyに対して、文字数11以降("/")の文字列を取得
            fileName = getKey.substr(index + 1);
        }

        // S3から録音データに関する情報を取得
        const s3GetCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: getKey
        });
        
        const s3GetRes = await s3Client.send(s3GetCommand);
        const info = await s3GetRes.Body.transformToString();
        const infoStr = JSON.parse(info);
        console.log(`==info==:${info}`);
        console.log(`==infoStr==:${infoStr}`);
        
        const streamName = infoStr.streamARN.split('stream/')[1].split('/')[0];
        const fragmentNumber = infoStr.startFragmentNumber;
        const streamARN = infoStr.streamARN;
        console.log(`==streamName==:${streamName}`);
        console.log(`==fragmentNumber==:${fragmentNumber}`);
        
        // Kinesis Video StreamsからRAWデータの取得
        const kvmInput = {
            StreamName: streamName,
            StreamARN: streamARN,
            StartSelector: {
                StartSelectorType: fragmentNumber,
            },
        };
        
        const kvmCommand = new GetMediaCommand(kvmInput);
        const data = await kvmClient.send(kvmCommand);

        // Kinesis Video StreamsからRAWデータの取得
        const raw = await getMedia(streamName, fragmentNumber);
        // RAWデータからWAVファイルを作成
        const wav = Converter.createWav(raw, 8000);
        
        // WAVファイルをS3に保存
        let tagging = ''; // 付加情報をタグに追加する
        tagging += "customerEndpoint=" + info.customerEndpoint + '&';
        tagging += "systemEndpoint=" + info.systemEndpoint + '&';
        tagging += "startTimestamp=" + info.startTimestamp;
        // await s3.put(bucketName, putKey + createKeyName()  + fileName + '.wav', Buffer.from(wav.buffer), tagging)

        const wavInput = new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: putKey + createKeyName()  + fileName + '.wav',
            Body: Buffer.from(wav.buffer),
            Tag: tagging
        });
        
        const wavRes = await s3Client.send(wavInput);
        
    } // for
}; // export const handler

// S3バケット保存時のオブジェクト名を生成
function createKeyName() {

    const date = new Date();    
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const mon = (date.getMonth() + 1);
    const day = date.getDate();
    const hour = date.getHours();

    const space = (n) => {
        console.log(`==n==${n}`);
        return ('0' + (n)).slice(-2);
    };

    let result = year + '/';
    result += space(mon) + '/';
    result += space(day) + '/';
    result += space(hour) + '/';
    return result;
} // createKeyName
    
// ebml「on」のインポート
let chunks = [];
let decoder = function () {}; // 下記に修正
// let decoder = ebml();
function decoderOn() {
    decoder.on = function (data, chunk) {
        if(chunk[1].name == 'SimpleBlock'){
            chunks.push(chunk[1].data);
        }
    
        for(let chunk of chunks){
            if(chunk[1].name == 'SimpleBlock'){
                chunks.push(chunk[1].data);
            }
        }
        return chunk;
    };
}
    
// export default decoderOn;
decoderOn();
    
console.log(`==decoder==${decoder}`);

// 録音データの取得・wavデータへの変換
async function getMedia(streamName, fragmentNumber) {
    // Endpointの取得
    let kvInput = {
        APIName: "GET_MEDIA",
        StreamName: streamName
    };
    
    const kvClient = new KinesisVideoClient({ region : region });
    const kvCommand = new GetDataEndpointCommand(kvInput);
    const end = await kvClient.send(kvCommand);

    // RAWデータの取得
    let kvmInput = {
        StartSelector: { 
            StartSelectorType: "FRAGMENT_NUMBER",
            AfterFragmentNumber:fragmentNumber,
        },
        StreamName: streamName
    };
    
    const kvmClient = new KinesisVideoMediaClient({ endpoint: end.DataEndpoint, region : region });
    const kvmCommand = new GetMediaCommand(kvmInput);
    const data = await kvmClient.send(kvmCommand);

    console.log('==chunks==');
    console.log(chunks);
    
    // ebml「write」へのインポート
    function decoderWrite() {
        decoder.write = function () {
            decoder.write(data["Payload"]);
            return data;
        };
    }
    
    // export default decoderWrite();
    decoderWrite();
    
   
    console.log('==chunks2==');
    console.log(chunks);
    
    // chunksの結合
    const margin = 4; // 各chunkの先頭4バイトを破棄する
    var sumLength = 0;
    chunks.forEach( chunk => {
        sumLength += chunk.byteLength - margin;
    });
    var sample = new Uint8Array(sumLength);
    var pos = 0;
    chunks.forEach(chunk => {
        let tmp = new Uint8Array(chunk.byteLength - margin);
        for(var e = 0; e < chunk.byteLength -  margin; e++){
            tmp[e] = chunk[e + margin];
        }
        sample.set(tmp, pos);
        pos += chunk.byteLength - margin;

    });
    console.log('==sample==');
    console.log(sample);
    return sample.buffer;
} // async function getMedia


    
class Converter {
    // WAVファイルの生成
    static createWav(samples, sampleRate) {
        const len = samples.byteLength;
        const view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(44 + len));
        this._writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
        view.setUint32(4, 32 + len, true);
        this._writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
        this._writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
        view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
        view.setUint16(20, 1, true); // リニアPCM
        view.setUint16(22, 1, true); // モノラル
        view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true); 
        view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 2, true);
        view.setUint16(32, 2, true);
        view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
        this._writeString(view, 36, 'data');
        view.setUint32(40, len, true);
        let offset = 44;
        const srcView = new DataView(samples);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i+=4, offset+=4) {
            view.setInt32(offset, srcView.getUint32(i), true);
        }
        return view;
    }

    static _writeString(view, offset, string) {
        for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
          view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
        }
    }
} // class Converter
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/d2undeg5aibtiw) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: コードを変更というのは、質問文に載っているこのコードに変更前のものがあるということでしょうか。もしその場合、どの部分が変わったのでしょうか。

Comment: AWS Labmda上の動作であれば、CloudWatch Logs上でconsole.logの結果やエラー出力などが残っていると思うので、まずはその確認から始めてみてはどうでしょうか。内容や設定等によってはログに直接的な原因が全て出力されており、自己解決できるかもしれません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
変更前のコードはリンク先に記載されているコードとなります。
CloudWatchのlogも確認しましたが、エラーは出力されておりません。
wavファイル自体は作成されるのですが、中身が空っぽなのが原因が特定できず、困っております。
よろしくお願いいたします。